# Как заменить указатели на классы?

Tags: java, android

В Delphi я использовать указатели, а в Яве еще плохо ориентируюсь. Как решить такую задачу?

Есть класс

```
public class CardData {
  public static String Name = "SAN";
  public static int month = 4;
  public static double ddd = 8;
  CardData{
  }
}
```

Есть класс состоящий из предыдущего

```
public class TypeCard {
  public static CardData ctN = new CardData() ;
  public static CardData ctD = new CardData() ; 
  public static CardData ctP = new CardData() ;
  }
```

Есть массив

```
TypeCard[] user = new TypeCard[4]
```

Как это все объединить в один класс, чтобы пользоваться примерно так:

```
user[0].ctN.Name = "NameCar" ;
```

но вместо названий ctN,ctD,ctP применять цифры или названия в String.

Comment: Не очень понятна суть вопроса. Равно как и почему все поля в классах `CardData` и `TypeCard` `static` - в таком случае смысла создавать объекты `CardData` и `TypeCard` нет. Если правильно спроектировать код, то не придётся напрямую задавать значения полей у полей.

Comment: static чтобы использовать как глобальные переменные.

Comment: Я вообще не понял цели, но написал вот такой класс `public enum CardType {

    ctN("SAN", 4, 8), ctD("SAT", 5, 6), ctP("TUE", 3, 5);

    private String Name;
    private int month;
    private double ddd;

    CardType(String name, int month, double ddd) {

        Name = name;
        this.month = month;
        this.ddd = ddd;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public double getDdd() {
        return ddd;
    }
}
`

Comment: Рассмотрение чем плохи глобальные переменные в этот вопрос не входит, но конкретно в случае поля `Name` (которое, по идее, должно быть `name`) вы можете поменять его значение так: `CardData.name = "NameCar;`. Создавать при этом какие-либо объекты не нужно.

Comment: @Tachkin в комментариях куча кода выглядит очень плохо. Стоило его на каком-нибудь сайте разместить.

Comment: @Regent, извиняюсь, не поддерживает комментарий форматирование. Мысль была предложить enum, как неизменяемую коллекцию, доступную поимени класса, что бы не писать 2 разных класса.

Comment: Предложенные варианты не совсем то, что надо. Попробую по другому сформулировать.

Comment: Описанный в самом вопросе вариант работает, переменные легко меняются на любые другие, НО используя конструкцию: user[0].ctN.Name = "NameCar" приходится вручную менять ctN на ctD или другую. Их может быть больше 20. Я хочу обращаться к ним как массиву т.е. user[0].[1].Name = "NameCar" (например в цикле). И полей в классе CardData очень много, просто привел три для примера.

Comment: Ох, мать моя.... Дружищще, а не попробовать ли тебе сделать интерфейс и много много реализаций? Ну, типа настоящее ООП замутить? ;)

Comment: Да давно бы уже замутил, знал бы как. Еще раз уточню задачу. Есть класс CalcAll(). Для всех расчетов. Ему я хочу одной строкой указать что входные данные находятся в одном из CardData, и рассчитанные данные поместить туда же и оставить их там. Чтобы потом я обратился к ним таким же способом. user[0].ctN.Name = "NameCar" или user[0].ctD.Name = "month". Попробую разобраться с интерфейсам.

Answer (score 0):

> но вместо названий ctN,ctD,ctP применять цифры или названия в String.

Ну можно в TypeCard сделать мап с этими объектами. Тогда будет что-то вроде

```
user[0].get("Название вашего экземпляра класса").Name = "NameCar";
```

Или можно в TypeCard сделать массив с этими объектами. Тогда будет что-то вроде

```
user[0].[1].Name = "NameCar";
```

Пример с HashMap

```
public class TypeCard {
Map<String, CardData > hashmap = new HashMap<String, CardData >();
public void init()
{
hashmap.put("ctN", new CardData());
hashmap.put("ctM", new CardData());
//...
}
}
```